# What should be included in a standard 4E D&D encounter? How would this be written in the adventure?

Tags: dnd-4e, encounter-design, adventure-writing

I'm a big D&D fan, but haven't played in ten years or so.  The last time I played, it was AD&D 2nd edition.  I am trying to write an adventure for a friend, and I'm sort of confused as to what needs to be included about monsters within the adventure text itself.  Do I just copy the info from the Monster Manual, or just put in the basic, most important info?  Thanks.  I'll clarify this if necessary!

Comment: "An adventure to run for a friend" (you are GMing, he is playing) or "an adventure a friend will run (you are authoring, he is GMing)?

Comment: Sorry, I am authoring, he is GM'ing.  He is halfway across the country.  I just wanted to put some of my ideas to use, he is running a few games, it works out for both of us :).  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Sample WOTC encounter]

Here is what a [typical (small) encounter produced by WOTC looks like](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/h1.pdf).

Notice what the monster stat blocks look like.  They provide some basic information and all that a DM needs to run the module.

So it includes

1. **Top Green Bar**

   - Name of Monster
   - Level of Monster
   - Monster Fighting style (Soldier, Brute, Solo, etc)
   - XP provided by Monster
   - Monster type (small, large, humanoid etc.)
   - Letter of the Monster corresponding to the Encounter Map
2. **Important Monster stats**

   - Initiative and Perception
   - Total HP and Bloodied values
   - AC, Wil, Ref, Fort
   - Immunities and  Speed and other combat related skills like stealth (if any)
3. **Monster Attacks**

   - Attacks have their own special icons to tell you what type of attack it is, and if its rechargeable etc.
4. **Additional Monster stats**

   - Alignment
   - Languages
   - Attribute Scores
5. **Equipment**

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make an encounter look familiar to 4E GMs by matching the format used in modules and dragon magazine, you will want to:

- Name the encounter
- Describe the context of the encounter
- List the creatures in the encounter along with the letter (or letters) used on the tactical map.
- Show a tactical map for the encounter
- Provide some read aloud text, and other "pre encounter" detail.
- List the stat blocks for the creatures in the encounter
- Provide suggested tactics
- Describe the features of the area, along with any special game effects of those features
- Describe any events, challenges or changes that may come up during or as a result of the encounter
- List any treasure found in the encounter.